# set text if bindable property is true

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin

I want to set text to a listview item if the property of the bindable object is true. For instance in a list of instructions, if the instruction was set as reviewed I want a label to show text "reviewed" else if not reviewed set text as "not reviewed"

Comment: Do you have any code you could share? It would be easier to help you if you could demonstrate what you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

Use either value converter or do binding to string and inside your view model return string based on your flag